# Use boto3 with kivy-ios

Tags: python, kivy, boto3

I'm developing an app with kivy using the boto3 library.
When I build my project on XCode, I have an error "AttributeError: module 'subprocess' has no attribute 'Popen'".
I don't understand why because I can launch my app with no problem from my computer but not with XCode...

Can someone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: [Why does the python multiprocess/subprocess module not work?](https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios#why-does-the-python-multiprocesssubprocess-module-not-work)

Answer (score 0):

I finally find a workaround thanks to this link : https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios/issues/372
But now, I have a new issue. boto3 use this file : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/multiprocessing/connection.py and Xcode gives me the following error  : "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_multiprocessing'"
If someone has an idea...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please improve the answer by providing code and update the question to include your new problem or ask a new question. Your answer should not contain a question.